# How calculate one side limit with WolframAlpha?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I read examples, and try:

```
lim ln(x+1) as x->inf from the left
```

but always wolfram alpha represent infinity as positive.

Comment: $\ln(x+1)$ doesn't exist in $\mathbb{R}$ for $x\leq -1$. How can you compute limit at $-\infty$? It is not possible

Comment: @Raffaele $\ln(x+1)$ does not exist for $x < -1$. The $=$ sign has not to be taken into account.

Comment: Could you possibly have $x\to\infty$ from the right? Seems to me like $x\to\infty$ without any direction specifications should work just fine.

Comment: @HenryTuring What do you mean? As long as I know $\log 0$ doesn't exist even in $\mathbb{C}$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write

Limit of  "*your function*" as $x$ -> $x_0$ (your point) from the left/right

In your case, specify "plus infinity" or $+\infty$. Or minus.

In any case, the $\log$ has no limit for points from the left. It does not exist.

Except all the points $x_0 > -1$, because you have $\ln(x+1)$.